# Finding set of rows in table based on matching rows from another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, relational-division

I know the topic is a bit vague at best, but cannot find a way to describe my problem better...

An example, I have the following two tables:

TableA

| IdA | Code | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1 |
| 123 | B | 2 |
| 123 | C | 3 |
| 456 | A | 4 |
| 456 | F | 6 |
| 456 | E | 7 |
| ... |  |  |

TableB

| IdB | Code | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 1 |
| X | B | 2 |
| X | C | 3 |
| Y | G | 2 |
| Y | D | 8 |
| Y | C | 3 |
| Z | A | 1 |
| Z | B | 2 |
| Z | C | 3 |
| Z | D | 5 |
| ... |  |  |

A set of records for a given IdA in TableA correlates to an equivalent set of records in TableB having a specific IdB.

For instance, for IdA = 123 in TableA, I have exactly three rows with certain codes and values, this would "map" to rows with IdB = X in TableB because it has the same combination of Codes and Values and the same number of rows. Note that it would not map to IdB = Z in TableB, because it has an additional row for Code D which IdA = 123 doesn't have in TableA.

Given only IdA, how to best write a query to find IdB?

If the codes and values were known, I could have done something similar to this:

```
SELECT b.IdB FROM TableB b
WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB x WHERE x.IdB = b.IdB AND x.Code = 'A' AND x.Value = '1') AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB x WHERE x.IdB = b.IdB AND x.Code = 'B' AND x.Value = '2') AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB x WHERE x.IdB = b.IdB AND x.Code = 'C' AND x.Value = '3') AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB x WHERE x.IdB = b.IdB) = 3
```

But now I'm only given a value for IdA, so I need to look up values from TableA and combine that in the query for TableB. Any clever ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a question of *[Relational Division Without Remainder](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/)*.**

There are many solutions, here is one:

- Take `TableB` and left join `TableA` to it
- But calculate a total over the whole set of values from A
- Group by `IdB`
- Filter so we only have rows where the total count is equal to the number of matches to A (because `COUNT(IdA)` only counts non-nulls) and the total count must also be the same as the total number of rows that we want to match to.

```sql
DECLARE @idA int = 123;

SELECT
  b.IdB
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      total = COUNT(*) OVER ()
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.IdA = @idA
) a ON b.Code = a.Code AND b.Value = a.Value
GROUP BY
  b.IdB
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(a.IdA)
  AND COUNT(*) = MIN(a.total);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57daeef085800436f985b0b2fc27aa86)